# How to identify the row being edited for dynamically added rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic

Have a set of rows which are  added dynamically. A row contains two dropdowns and three textfields and are student objects.

Following is my code :

```
<tr class="dynamicRow">

<div class="inputField">
                                    <td><b><bean:message key="label.student.code" />:</b>
                                    </td><td >
                                     <logic:present name="studentList">
                                        <html:select property="dgList[0].stuCreate"
                                        styleId="stuSelect" >
                                            <html:option value="">
                                                <bean:message key="label.student.select.code" />
                                            </html:option>
                                            <html:optionsCollection name="studentform"
                                                property="studentList" label="label" value="value" />
                                        </html:select>
                                    </logic:present> 
                                        </td>
                                    </div>
```

...and 3 more fields like this.

My Requirement : When values are populated in the pop up with x number of rows and if I change any field value then how to identify that row has been edited and get the field value before and after editing to update in database? Kindly help.

Code that worked: onchange() called for each field in that row. Means for one row just to check if the value has been changed onchange() is called 5 times. Can this be optimised . Kindly help.

Comment: Where is `pop-up` code ? Also , update your question with what you have tried to achieve above..

Comment: Pop up code is similar to this. Create will call a javascript function to populate values in the pop up.

Comment: I tried calling onchange() for all fields to check if a field value has been changed in that row. That I think is a conventional method. Can you please suggest a better solution.

Comment: So that worked or not ? did you any error ?

Comment: Yes it worked but onchange() is called for every field .Means for each row it is called 5(number of fileds in that row) times.How to optimise this?Kindly help.

Comment: Can you add that in your asked question ?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: You need to loop through all row to check that sorry  i don't know if there is any method to do so